# Hand Selected Points and Homography precision.

Tags: computer-vision

I have two calibrated cameras, so I know the essential an intrinsic matrices and I have computed the homography between a set of hand selected points. They are hand selected because the selection of the points requires domain knowledge beyond which automatic point selection cannot be relied upon - that is, it is a expert selecting the points. That said, the expert will be off slightly by a few pixels and a least squares solution (SVD) is used of course. I'm thinking that I want to assist the surgeon in selecting the corresponding points by computing the epipolar line in the corresponding image as the user selects points. This means that I need the fundamental matrix from the two camera matrices. All the examples that I see say "Let's assume that camera 1 is at

\begin{array}{c|c}
  I&0
\end{array}

and camera 2 is at

\begin{array}{c|c}
  R&t
\end{array}

but my first camera is not at the origin.

How does that change the computation of F?

Thanks

Comment: I’ll need to review this material in order to provide a proper answer, but my first inclination is to say that the cameras’ _actual_ stances don’t change much. It’s only their _relative_ stances that are captured by the fundamental and essential matrices, which is why pretty much everyone assumes $[I\mid\mathbf 0]$ for the first camera. Note, for instance, that in terms of the camera matrices $P$ and $P'$ and epipole $\mathbf e'$, $F=[\mathbf e']_\times P'P^+$, so the non-relative parts of the world transformations cancel—$F$ determines the camera matrices up to a projective transformation.

Comment: I’m not sure that really matters, though. You write that you have the essential matrix $E$ and intrinsic matrices $K$ and $K'$. Can’t you recover the fundamental matrix from these using $E={K'}^TFK$?